# ZF2 mysql functions in select using TableGateway

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm using ZF2 TableGateway and want to do a select such as `where md5(email) = $hash`

I've tried to do this in the select with `->select(array('md5(email)' => $hash));` but this doesn't work, I get column not found.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Huh? This has nothing to do with passwords

Comment: apologies miss read; thought it was the password field

Comment: Ah no worries, this is a hack job on top of hack job, just need to be able to do a mysql function in the select against a field

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend\Db\TableGateway.

```
                  use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
                  use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
                  use Zend\Debug\Debug;

$driver =  array('db' => array('driver' => 'Pdo', 'dsn'=>'mysql:dbname=zf2;host=localhost;
             charset=utf8', 'user'=>'root','pass'=>'pass')
        );
$db = new Adapter($driver);
                  $sql = new Sql($db);
                  $select = $sql->select();
                  $select->from('YourTable');

                  $select->where(array('md5(email)' => $hash));
        OR

                  $select->where->equalTo('md5(email)', $hash);
```

that may work. untested.

Comment: Doesn't work, `md5('email')` will do a php md5 hash of 'email' as oppose to being executed on the mysql server

Comment: Hm, I don't see where on TableGateway.

Answer (score 0):

using table gateway is much easier if your query involve single table. from your query below is the solution

```
->select(array('md5(email) = ?' => $hash));
```

would work, this will return resultset object to get the result use

```
$resultset->current(); //to get the current row
```